# Question about differentiating of CDF

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be $\mathcal{U}(0,1)$ and $Y=X(1-X),$ then the $S_Y=[0,\frac{1}{4}]$. Find $F_Y(y)$.

The answer is \begin{align} F_Y(y)&=P(Y \leq y) \\[6pt] &=P(X \in \{x:u(x) \leq y\}) \\[6pt] &= P\left(X \leq \frac{1- \sqrt{1-4y}}{2}\right) + P\left(X \geq \frac{1+ \sqrt{1-4y}}{2}\right) \\[6pt] &=F_X\left(\frac{1- \sqrt{1-4y}}{2}\right) + 1- F_X\left(\frac{1+ \sqrt{1-4y}}{2}\right) \end{align}

By differentiating, $f_Y(y)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4y}} \cdot 1+0- (- \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4y}}) \cdot 1=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-4y}}$

Why are we differentiating $F_X(    )$, the thing inside the parentheses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an application of the chain rule.

$$\begin{align}\dfrac{\mathrm d~F_X(g(y))}{\mathrm d ~y\hspace{8ex}} &= \dfrac{\mathrm d~F_X(g(y))}{\mathrm d ~g(y)\hspace{5ex}}\cdot\dfrac{\mathrm d~g(y)}{\mathrm d ~y\hspace{3ex}} \\[2ex]& =f_X(g(y))\cdot\dfrac{\mathrm d~g(y)}{\mathrm d ~y\hspace{3ex}}\end{align}$$

Comment: And so g(y) is the thing inside the parentheses, what's the expression for $F_X$? I only see they differentiate g(y)

Comment: $F_X$ is the cumulative distribution function for $X$, the uniformly distributed random variable over the unit interval.$$F_X(x)=\begin{cases}0&:&\qquad x<0\\x&:& 0\leqslant x< 1\\1 &:& 1\leqslant x\end{cases}$$